# is there a way to save key into Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to save a key in Android so that even if it is rooted the key cannot be retrieved by anyone. Not shared preferences but something else which places the key in highly secured place in Android.

Basically to save dynamic key sent from the server.

Comment: You cannot save anything on any computer if you want certainty that your user cannot access it.

Comment: What about encrypting your data and storing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a solution , i did this solution to save private messages ... if you like this you may try ... i have convert the message in encrypted form using Base 64 or you may also use AES/DES algorithms ... encrypted form is not readable by humans so its the safest method to save your key.. when ever you want your key just decrypt it.

Answer (score 2):

As someone mentioned, you can encrypt it with AES/DES key. For extra safety, you can add unique device ID to it. For example:

```
String secureString = "some text";
String aesKey;
String uniqueKey = app.getUniqueDeviceID() + aesKey;
//encrypt using uniqueKey
```

Comment: the unique device id changes if you do factory reset or root your phone right ?

Comment: SO If I am using the key below to authenticate the user then it would be different the next time he logs in to my app right?

Comment: @JamesPatrick official documentation states for ANDROID_ID:
A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated on the device's first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the device. (The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.) 
The problem with android id is that sometimes it can be null.

Comment: Using only AES or DES should be enough for your security, I just suggested unique device ID as means of additional security.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to save a key in android OS so that even if it is
>   rooted the key cannot be retrieved by anyone.

Generally, no. You can only make it harder by [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation).

But you will never have 100% guarantee. Lets say I'm a root on my device. You save something in my memory. I can always look what I have in my memory. If I'm patient enough I can discover your key or anything it was.

Comment: So how do I save a key which can be used everytime I send a request to server??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. A root user could access any place the system can, so you can try to hide that key, but I think you can't control it's access.

Comment: I would like to use a key which sends it to server everytime yu make a request how do I dot that or way do I SAVE IT ?

Comment: The only way is what the others users said in this topic: encrypt your key (AES/DES or whatever) and save it in your app's dir.